# Does the apache/php5 package include Zend?

Tags: apache2, php, lamp, zend

I'm loading up a fresh development computer for one of my new hires.  As a standard, I put in a very basic LAMP server on all of our development computers.  The one I'm currently loading is running 12.04 x64.  I load in the following packages:

- apache2
- mysql-server
- php5
- phpmyadmin

And I pretty much say yes to all of their dependencies.

I put in a phpinfo() file into the root of my /var/www to double check what comes with the base install of LAMP, and was surprised to find a section on Zend.  Specifically it says:

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend
>   Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Does that mean that the base install of a LAMP server includes Zend?  We don't use Zend anywhere in our stack, and I don't love the idea of it being installed on our computers without any specific use.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK zend engine is the core of php and according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Engine) its vm of php. I think you cannot avoid zend engine if you need to work with php. But if you are talking about Zend-Framework it won't install during LAMP installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question. To run PHP code, you need a [program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Implementations) that can understand understand PHP. This is either [Zend Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5377370/632951) (the [branch](https://archive.is/dnUk4) by [Dmitry](http://news.php.net/php.internals/73888) called [PHPNG](https://www.quora.com/What-is-PHPNG) has been [merged on](https://archive.is/yeLCj) v7.0), [Websphere sMash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Zero),  [Phalanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalanger_(compiler)#Compatibility), [HipHop VM](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HHVM),  [HippyVM](http://hippyvm.com/), [Parrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrot_virtual_machine), [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/quercus-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp#existing), or some [other  program](http://google.com/search?q=alternatives%20to%20zend%20engine).  (Note: Every engine is saying that they are faster than every other engine. Note note: Zend admits "[...*it's a fact that HHVM is slightly faster, by 10%*](http://blog.zend.com/2014/07/17/php-next-generation-outperforming-facebooks-hhvm/#.VbdGvfmqqkp)".)

You had most likely downloaded a PHP engine from Zend since your `phpinfo()` is showing "*program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine...*" which is exactly what you would have seen if you had downloaded it from [php.net/releases](http://php.net/release):

```
C:\php-5.6.7-Win32-VC11-x86>php -r"phpinfo();"|find/i"zend"|find/i"engine"
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

(Above is Windows' `find` command. For Ubuntu, use `grep`.)

There's also no [trace of Zend Guard or Zend Optimizer](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/zend/enable-zend-optimizer-or-zend-guard#page_views) in your `phpinfo()` output so you indeed have the "basic" version. Either that, or your server had some settings mixed up.